# VS Code extension no longer including line number in Apex test failure output

Tags: apex, unit-test, salesforcedx-cli, vs-code

When I run Apex tests from VS Code (leveraging Salesforce CLI), I'm accustomed to the output telling me what line my tests failed on in the event of failure.

I've noticed a recent change (just in the last few weeks) where the output no longer contains this type of info.  Here's an example of the output I'm getting now:

```
09:10:17.971 Starting Run Apex Tests

=== Test Summary
NAME                 VALUE                           
───────────────────  ────────────────────────────────
Outcome              Failed                          
Tests Ran            1                               
Pass Rate            0%                              
Fail Rate            100%                            
Skip Rate            0%                              
Test Run Id          7070v00001ZbNXl                 
Test Execution Time  0 ms                            
Org Id               00D0v000000#######              
Username             testuser@test.com


=== Test Results
TEST NAME                              OUTCOME  MESSAGE                                                           RUNTIME (MS)
─────────────────────────────────────  ───────  ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────  ────────────
MyTest.myMethod  Fail     System.AssertException: Assertion Failed: Expected: 1, Actual: 0  null        

09:10:52.151 Finished Run Apex Tests
```

What changed?  And is there a config change I can make to get it back to how it was before?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've confirmed that this is indeed happening... but only in the VS Code Extension. If you run the test directly:

```
sfdx force:apex:test:run -w 10 -t TestFail
```

You'll get the correct output.

## VS Code Extension Output

```
10:54:53.884 Starting Run Apex Tests

=== Test Summary
NAME                 VALUE               
───────────────────  ────────────────────
Outcome              Failed              
Tests Ran            1                   
Pass Rate            0%                  
Fail Rate            100%                
Skip Rate            0%                  
Test Run Id          7071T00008ysPBh     
Test Execution Time  401 ms              
Org Id               00D500000REDACTED  
Username             redacted@redacted.com

=== Test Results
TEST NAME               OUTCOME  MESSAGE                                                                                                                                                                                 RUNTIME (MS)
─────────────  ───────  ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────  ────────────
TestFail.test  Fail     System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY, insufficient access rights on cross-reference id: 001300000000ABC: []  401         

10:55:35.838 Finished Run Apex Tests
```

## SFDX CLI Output

```
=== Test Results
TEST NAME      OUTCOME  MESSAGE                                                                                                                                                                                          RUNTIME (MS)
─────────────  ───────  ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────  ────────────
TestFail.test  Fail     System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY, insufficient access rights on cross-reference id: 001300000000ABC: []  436        
                        Class.TestFail.test: line 6, column 1

=== Failures
FULLNAME       MESSAGE
─────────────  ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
TestFail.test  System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY, insufficient access rights on cross-reference id: 001300000000ABC: []
            C:/Users/brian/workspace/force-app/main/default/classes/TestFail.cls:6:1

=== Test Summary
NAME                 VALUE
───────────────────  ─────────────────────────────────────────
Outcome              Failed
Tests Ran            1
Passing              0
Failing              1
Skipped              0
Pass Rate            0%
Fail Rate            100%
Test Start Time      Jan 22, 2021 10:52 AM
Test Execution Time  436 ms
Test Total Time      436 ms
Command Time         13937 ms
Hostname             https://redacted.my.salesforce.com
Org Id               00D5000000REDACTED
Username             redacted@redacted.com
Test Run Id          7071T00008ysPB5
User Id              0055000000REDACTED
```

I'll bring this up with some people and see if we can get it fixed. For now, use the SFDX CLI from the Terminal tab to get the correct output.

---

Edit:

[I have a response](https://twitter.com/stephaniemaddox/status/1353775813498290176). There is some internal development occurring with the plugin that is causing this problem. It will be corrected later in the year. Until then, you can get the correct behavior by going in to VS Code's Settings and disabling the `Use Apex Library` setting. This will force the extension to use the CLI instead of the internal library.

Comment: Thanks so much as always @sfdcfox.  I didn't realize the VS Code extension might be using something other than the CLI to run these tests.  Just renamed the question to better reflect this understanding.

Comment: @MatthewSouther It is using the CLI. I presume that it's somehow incorrectly parsing the output. I'm in the process of getting a ticket to have it fixed. Thanks for bringing it to our attention.

Comment: @sfdcfox is this a ticket on the extension's GitHub or somewhere else? I'd be interested in following the issue so I can see when it's resolved.

Comment: @nbrown So far, it's just disappeared into the woodworks. [This tweet](https://twitter.com/asksalesforce/status/1352719646550581255) was the response I have so far.

Comment: @MatthewSouther I've edited this answer. You can disable the "Use Apex Library" option in VS Code in order to use the CLI instead of the (currently broken) internal library. It will be fixed at some point in the future (#SafeHarbor).

Comment: Looks like in v51.2.0 they've taken test failures out of the Output tab entirely and put them in the Problems tab (which I think is a lot better anyway)